# Flutter Realm authentication not working, RealmException : non-zero custom status code considered fatal

Tags: mongodb, flutter, realm

I'm trying by following the docs to register and then login with realm.
Unfortunatly I got an error `RealmException : non-zero custom status code considered fatal` when trying to do :
`authProvider.registerUser(email, password)`
or :
`app.logIn(emailCred);`

I created a repo to reproduce here (look for the `_handleSubmitted` function inside `register_view` or `login_view` files) :
https://github.com/geosebas/flutter_realm_auth

You will just need a mongodb free tier account with an empty app and email/password auth enabled (with no confirm email and default reset function)

I'm new to both flutter and realm so the solution may be very simple, please help me !

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! In general, code should be included in the question - links break and if that happens future readers will not know what the question was about. Also, some general troubleshooting should be included - stepping through you code line by line until it does something unexpected is Best Practice. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finally got the solution !

By reading in details the doc, I saw that you cannot choose the GCP as a deployment region for app service, but my atlas cluster is in GCP, so by default when you create an app on app service, it will be on GCP and nothing (or at least user auth) will work.

IMHO, it’s a very annoying bug as you cannot debug anything and the error you will get mean nothing.

Have a nice day :slight_smile:

PS : Here the post on mongodb forum with a bit more details : https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/flutter-realm-auth-not-working/176195

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when running in the iOS debugger, and the issue was that I needed to add client network entitlements.

I added the following code to the files `DebugProfile.entitlements` and `Release.entitlements`:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

This solution was inspired by a [similar user issue with flutter firebase](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7908#issuecomment-1025663361).

Comment: Hello, you will have a similar problem on android with internet permissions. More info in the doc here :) 
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/networking